# It seems the current standard draft cannot interpret why two structured binding declaration conflict with each other

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct A{
    int a;
};
struct B{
    int b;
};
auto&& [x] = A{};  //#1
auto&& [x] = B{};  //#2
int main(){
}
```

In this example, [all compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/7Mbh5x) give an error that the `x` at #2 conflicts with that introduced at #1. However, IIUC, there's no rule in the post-C++20 working draft standard which can interpret what's the reason.

First, in my opinion, the declaration at #2 and the declaration at #1 declare the same entity. They correspond due to:
[basic.scope#scope-3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#scope-3)

> Two declarations correspond if they **(re)introduce the same name**, both declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless
>
> > [...]

They declare the same entity per [basic.link#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8)

> Two declarations of entities declare the same entity if, considering declarations of unnamed types to introduce their names for linkage purposes, if any ([dcl.typedef], [dcl.enum]), **they correspond ([basic.scope.scope]), have the same target scope that is not a function or template parameter scope**, and either
>
> > - **they appear in the same translation unit**, or
> > - [...]

So, as far as now, they declare the same entity and they shouldn't be considered as potentially conflict per [basic.scope#scope-4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#scope-4)

> Two declarations potentially conflict if they correspond and **cause their shared name to denote different entities([basic.link])**. The program is ill-formed if, in any scope, a name is bound to two declarations that potentially conflict and one precedes the other ([basic.lookup]).

Since they denote the same entity, as aforementioned, they do not potentially conflict.

They still do not violate this rule:
[basic.link#11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#11)

> For any two declarations of an entity E:
>
> > - If one declares E to be a variable or function, the other shall declare E as one of the same type.
> > - [...]

Since structured bindings are not mentioned in this list, they do not violate this rule.  Similar, they do not violate One-definition rule

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, template, default argument for a parameter (for a function in a given scope), or default template argument.

At least, according to what the relevant rules say, the two declarations in this example shouldn't result in any program ill-formed. If I don't miss some other rules, Can it be considered as vague in the standard which cannot interpret why two structured binding declarations conflict with each other in this case? This case is more underspecified in the [N4861](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/)

Comment: How on earth can two variables initialised with different expressions, with different _types_ even, be considered "the same entity"??

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  structured binding is not **variable**.

Comment: @jackX: No, but it does introduce a name, and that name denotes an entity. Why do you believe that those names denote the same entity?

Comment: @NicolBolas Because the rule says they're the same entity unless you can find out the rule says they're not.

Comment: Also, your references don't correspond correctly to the [actual C++20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/). You're referencing a future work-in-progress version of the standard, not the current one.

Comment: @jackX: No, you have to explain how that rule says that they're the same entity. I don't see that anywhere; you merely declare that the bold text says that they're the same, and it doesn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok. Do you agree such two declarations correspond  according to [basic.scope#scope-3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#scope-3)? If you agree, then we continue to the next step.

Comment: @jackX: Can you point out where that is in an actual standard, not a work-in-progress? C++23 is not finished and may not at any particular moment be entirely consistent with itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas  I have removed the tag c++20. Rather, this question is talking about the current draft.

Comment: No compiler implements the current draft. Since your question is about why *compilers* behave a certain way, your question doesn't make sense; they're not expected to follow the draft standard.

Comment: @NicolBolas However, what I reference in this question is the content of P1787, which has amended the vague in the last standard and that part has been implemented by the current compiler.

Comment: @jackX: "*that part has been implemented by the current compiler*" I'm very curious as to how you *know* that.

Comment: @NicolBolas So, in your opinion, how do you interpret this example by using actual C++20?

Comment: This all seems rather pointless, doesn't it? If you think there's an editorial problem in the draft standard, submit a proposed fix to the team.

Comment: @jackX: I interpret it by not bothering. Name scoping rules are a jumbled, nightmare mess of nonsense, and it's best to just do what your compiler tells you and/or avoid reusing names in places where it would be at all reasonable for them to conflict. Knowing too much about abstract esoterica of C++ naming only makes it easier to write code that makes no sense to the reader. That is, whether that code "works" or not is irrelevant because you shouldn't write it to begin with.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It's not an editorial issue. It's exactly the content of P1787. I just it's vague for **structured binding** but I'm not sure I don't miss some other rule that can interpret this.

Comment: @NicolBolas No offense, I don't think this is a correct way to answer the question tagged with **language-lawyer**.

Comment: @jackX: That's why it's a *comment*, not an answer. If your question had asked where in the C++20 standard it causes these declarations to conflict, I wouldn't have posted anything at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a missing case in [basic.link]/11: that if one (of the two declarations) declares a structured binding, the program is ill-formed.  (One could alternatively merely require that the other also declare a structured binding and then extend the list in [basic.def.odr]/1, but that’s more complicated and suggests that it might be possible to redefine it in another translation unit.)

Comment: I think it's already covered: Structured bindings are declarations ([dcl.struct.bind]/2), and the form of the declaration declares a variable. [basic.def]/2 says that all declarations are also definitions, with 20 exceptions, none of which apply. And since it is a definition of a variable, [basic.def.odr]/1 applies.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Structured bindings are just names—sometimes variables are declared implicitly as part of the meaning of the declaration, but those have unique names.  That said, the definitions of “variable” and “entity” have always been infirm, so it’s hard to be sure.  (I’d be glad for you to be right that my work is a bit less defective!)

Comment: @RaymondChen structured bindings are not **variable** even if it will create a unique name variable (underlying variable). However, it does not mean the structured bindings are variable [dcl.struct.bind#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#1), [basic.pre#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.pre#3)

Comment: @DavisHerring The latter alternative does make the standard more complex. IIUC, the name introduced by an identifier in the structured binding declaration has no linkage, because  [basic.link#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3) and [basic.link#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4) do not mention **structured bindings** at all.  It seems we cannot consider **structured binding** as a variable since structured bindings have an individual category in the list of [entity](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.pre#3).

Answer (score 1):

You are citing text from a working draft of a post-C++20 version of the language. As such, the behavior it describes is not likely implemented by any compiler currently existing. As it is a *working* draft, it likely contains a number of language defects and/or bugs, so trying to learn from it is not a productive activity.

All of the "correspond" language you cite is adopted from P1787, which is not part of any C++ standard actual compilers implement. As such, compilers are providing you with the C++20 functionality, and under those rules, these clearly conflict.

There may be some defective wording in P1787, but that's expected with complex proposals and working drafts of a standard. File a defect report on it.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean. In other words, I just want to examine whether my understanding of these rules is right? If you agree with my understanding of these rules cited in my question and at least agree with my analysis, then I can post an issue based on this version of the draft.

Comment: Could you modify your answers to add the interpretation by using the current c++20 standard to interpret why this example is ill-formed. Thanks for that.